# How to combine keys and values without looping with Underscore?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

```js
var request = {
    headers: {
        "CONTENT-TYPE": "application/json",
        "accept": "application/json"
    }
};
```

Purpose is to get the plain object, but with **"normalized" keys**. How can I combine `keys` and `vals` with Underscore?

```js
var normalize = function(h) { return h.toUpperCase(); },
    keys = _.map(_.keys(request.headers), normalize),
    vals = _.values(request.headers);

// Now combine (no obvious looping) keys and vals to obtain
// {
//     headers: {
//         "CONTENT-TYPE": "application/json",
//         "ACCEPT": "application/json"
//     }
// }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you consider `_.each` to be an "obvious" looping construct?

```
var normalize = function(h) { return h.toUpperCase(); },
    normalizedHeaders = {};

_.each(request.headers, function(value, key) {
    normalizedHeaders[normalize(key)] = value;
});
```

You could also do it with a reduction, if you prefer:

```
var reducer = function(result, v, k) { result[normalize(k)] = v; return result; },
    normalizedHeaders = _.reduce(request.headers, reducer, {});
```

Either way there's going to be a loop under the covers, though.

Comment: Not bad! Of course there will be a loop somewhere :) but I prefer a compact way! Thanks!